# Implement a second column of checkboxes alongside a checked listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, checkbox, listbox

I am creating some UI for a graphing tool at the moment, and I was wondering if anyone has come across/ knows how to implement a checked list box with 2 check boxes. I have had a look on both google and SO and I can't find anything.

My reason for using this is I want to use as little space as possible for controls to maximise plotting space. Currently I have two checked listboxes to show which axis a Parameter is plotted on, one for each axis. Both of the list boxes contain the same text and their checked status is related to each other. I can have 3 check cases False True, True False, False False but not True True. These denoted respecitivley data on right axis, data on left axis, data not plotted.

I would like to have two checkboxes on a single list box in a similar manner to a checked listbox, hopefully benefitting from the built in controls a listbox has eg user adding values and scrolling.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean one check box on the left and one on the right of the text?

Comment: I would prefer both next to each other on the left of the text.

Comment: @Pezzzz: If your intention is to have any combination of the three states selectable, couldn't you just use a set checkbox controls without a listbox?

Comment: @Malice I want the user to be able to dynamically add Parameters to the list box and have the benefits of scrollbars, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this really quickly, you could just put a tablelayoutpanel next to the checked list box and every time you add an item to the listbox, you could add a check box to the tablelayoutpanel (I would subclass listbox to do this). Then when a check box is clicked you can look up its row using `GetRow()` and check which list box item it matches.

Comment: I will have a look into this

Comment: Also, you could override the ListBoxItem class to have a reference to its check box in the table layout panel.